# Bash Script to loop through list to check server status

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create a script that will ping amongst other things, remote servers held in a list.

This is what i have so have, but keep getting this error:

**./monitor_sats.sh: cannot make pipe for command substitution: Too many open files.**

This is my code, thanks for helping.

```
 #!/bin/bash


 function ping {

   for i in `cat server_list`
   do
     ping -c1 ${i} > /dev/null
       if [ ${?} -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "$(tput setaf 2)ON$(tput sgr0)"
     else
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)OFF$(tput sgr0)"
     fi
   done
}



 echo "AMSTERDAM - Server  $(ping) "
 echo "HONG KONG - Server  $(ping) "
 echo "LONDON    - Server  $(ping) "
 echo "SINGAPORE - Server  $(ping) "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change function name as below;

```
#!/bin/bash
function pingToServer {
  for i in `cat server_list`
   do
    ping -c1 ${i} > /dev/null
       if [ ${?} -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "$(tput setaf 2)ON$(tput sgr0)"
     else
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)OFF$(tput sgr0)"
     fi
   done
}

 echo "AMSTERDAM - Server  $(pingToServer) "
 echo "HONG KONG - Server  $(pingToServer) "
 echo "LONDON    - Server  $(pingToServer) "
 echo "SINGAPORE - Server  $(pingToServer) "
```

you can also use this;

```
#!/bin/bash
Countries=("AMSTERDAM" "HONG KONG" "LONDON" "SINGAPORE")
counter=0
cat server_list | while read server; 
do
 ping -c1 ${server} > /dev/null
 if [ ${?} -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "${Countries[$counter]} - SERVER- $(tput setaf 2)ON$(tput sgr0)"
     else
         echo "${Countries[$counter]} - SERVER-$(tput setaf 1)OFF$(tput sgr0)"
     fi
    counter=$(($counter+1))
done
```

Comment: Mustafa you LEGEND :)

But it does repeat ON for each IP in the file for each country. Is there a way to limit the to just the country & IP.

Comment: @ChristianWatts : I updated ans. Maybe this could help you

Comment: Done with pleasure

Comment: @ChristianWatts Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This script looks syntactically correct but there is something wired: why ping the same list of servers for different cities ?

This make me feel you don't give the whole context...

Also, can you give the output of `ulimit -a` ? and tell the size of the list ?

Comment: Thanks Setop. The list has 20 IP's  which will match the Country echo.
I will be running commands using password-less SSH as well


    `core file size          (blocks, -c) 0`
     `data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited`
     `scheduling priority             (-e) 0`
     `file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited`
    `pending signals                 (-i) 15845`
    `max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64`
     `max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited`
     `open files                      (-n) 1024`
    ` pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8`

Comment: Mustafa spotted the issue : you have an infinite recursion as your function has the same name as the command you intend to invoke. Bash lookup functions before commands. Just change the function name as Mustafa suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(cat list_server) ; 
do ping -c 1 -w 1 $i > /dev/null && echo "$i - OK" || echo "$i - NOK" ; 
done
```